# LINQ Query Only Returning Last Entity In In-Memory Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am working on a method that returns a list of entities in our database. We are using Entity Framework Core v6.0.13.

In the unit tests, we've locally seeded the entities as such:

```
 private TopologyDBContext _topologyDbContext;
        private StopPointRepository _stopPointRepository;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Create an in-memory database for testing.
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TopologyDBContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TopologyTestDB")
                .Options;

            _topologyDbContext = new TopologyDBContext(options);
            _stopPointRepository = new StopPointRepository(_topologyDbContext);

            SeedTestData();


        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _topologyDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }

        private void SeedTestData()
        {
            var typeCodeOne = new NaptanTypeCodes("RLY", "NaptanFerryBerth", false, "Ferry", "Stop", 85000);
            var typeCodeTwo = new NaptanTypeCodes("ntc2", "className2", false, "Air", "type2", 2);
            var typeCodeThree = new NaptanTypeCodes("ntc3", "className3", true, "BusCoach", "type3", 3);
            var typeCodeFour = new NaptanTypeCodes("ntc4", "className4", false, "BusCoach", "type4", 4);
            var typeCodeFive = new NaptanTypeCodes("ntc5", "className5", true, "BusCoach", "type5", 5);

            var modeFerry = new Mode("Ferry", "Description", null, null, true, null, null, null, null, null, true, null,
                DateTime.UtcNow, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            var modeAir = new Mode("Air", "Description", null, null, true, null, null, null, null, null, true, null,
                DateTime.UtcNow, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);


            var modeBusCoach = new Mode("BusCoach", "DescriptionOne", null, null, true, null, null, null, null, null, true, null,
                DateTime.UtcNow, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            
            var modeFerryList = new List<Mode>() {modeFerry};
            var modeAirList = new List<Mode>() { modeAir};
            var modeFerryAirList = new List<Mode>() { modeFerry, modeAir};
            var modeBusCoachList = new List<Mode>() { modeBusCoach};

            var stopPoint1 = new StopPoint("9100SIDCUP0", "Sidcup", "indicator1", "stopLetter1", 000, "910GSIDCUP",
                "RLY", 1, 2, 1001249, true, typeCodeOne, modeFerryList);
            _topologyDbContext.StopPoints.Add(stopPoint1);

            var stopPoint2 = new StopPoint("atco2", "commonName2", "indicator2", "stopLetter2", 2, "parentAtcoCode2",
                "ntc2", 3.3, 4.4, 2, false, typeCodeTwo, modeFerryAirList);
            _topologyDbContext.StopPoints.Add(stopPoint2);

            var stopPoint3 = new StopPoint("atco3", "commonName3", "indicator3", "stopLetter3", 3, "parentAtcoCode3",
                "discriminator3", 5.5, 6.6, 3, true, typeCodeThree, modeBusCoachList);
            _topologyDbContext.StopPoints.Add(stopPoint3);

            var stopPoint4 = new StopPoint("atco4", "commonName4", "indicator4", "stopLetter4", 4, "parentAtcoCode4",
                "discriminator4", 7.7, 8.8, 4, false, typeCodeFour, modeBusCoachList);
            _topologyDbContext.StopPoints.Add(stopPoint4);

            var stopPoint5 = new StopPoint("atco5", "commonName5", "indicator5", "stopLetter5", 5, "parentAtcoCode5",
                "discriminator5", 9.9, 10.1, 5, true, typeCodeFive, modeFerryList);
            _topologyDbContext.StopPoints.Add(stopPoint5);


            _topologyDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

We've then tested it like such:

```
public async Task GetAllStopPoints_StopPointsInRepository_ReturnsAllStopPoints()
        {
            // Act
            var allStopPoints = await _stopPointRepository.GetAllStopPoints();

            var firstStopPoint = allStopPoints.FirstOrDefault();

            // Assert
            allStopPoints.Count().Should().Be(5);
}
```

Which passes.

However these tests do not:

```
 [Test]
        public async Task GetByModeStopPointsRequestAsync_GivenListOfModes_ReturnsBusCoachStopPointsOnly()
        {
            // Arrange
            var modes = new List<string> { "BusCoach" };



            // Act
            var result = await _stopPointRepository.GetStopPointsByModeAsync(modes);
            var firstSp = result.First();
            var secondSp = result.ElementAt(1);
            var thirdSp = result.ElementAt(2);
            var actual1 = firstSp.NaptanTypeCode.NaptanMode;
            var actual2 = secondSp.NaptanTypeCode.NaptanMode;
            var actual3 = thirdSp.NaptanTypeCode.NaptanMode;

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count()); // should be 3 BusCoach
            Assert.That(actual1, Is.EqualTo("BusCoach"));
            Assert.That(actual2, Is.EqualTo("BusCoach"));
            Assert.That(actual3, Is.EqualTo("BusCoach"));
        }
```

The weird thing is when we run it in debug, the final StopPoint entity is returned. So in this case StopPoint5 is returned. When we change the Mode, it becomes StopPoint4.

The method to return the StopPoints is currently this:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<StopPoint>> GetStopPointsByModeAsync(IEnumerable<string> modes)
        {
            return  await _dbSet
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.NaptanTypeCode.NaptanTypeCodesModes)
                .Include(i => i.Modes)
                .Where(n => n.Modes.Any(m => modes.Contains(m.Name)))
                .ToListAsync();

        }
```

The method is exactly the same as the one to get all StopPoints, only nothing is passed in to the method and the where statement is not there either.

Originally the StopPoints were passed in as a list, so we tried experimenting with putting the in individually. I have with no luck been trying to write a foreach loop to get all the returned SP's, then only return the ones with the correct mode.

I think the issue is in the LINQ query and how it is filtering, as it only returns the final one in the collection.

Comment: It looks like from all the StopPoints you added, only `stopPoint3` and `stopPoint4` have the `modeBusCoachList` mode list, therefore, when you call `GetStopPointsByModeAsync` with `"BusCoach"`, I expect 2 results, not 3, so I think `Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count());` is failing as expected. In fact, I even expect `result.ElementAt(2)` to throw an exception.

Comment: Without an `OrderBy` no order is guaranteed. The server is free to return the data in the cheapest way. The in-memory provider isn't a real database either and only meant for simple testing. There are no tables at all, it's just a container of items. `Include` has no effect because the objects are already in memory. Without an `OrderBy` though, again, the order isn't guaranteed. If the items are stored in a HashSet or Dictionary, the order is *implementation dependent*. In a database, different filtering/join algorithms will change the result order

Comment: Even if HashSet/Dictionary store values in the hash order, the hash algorithm can and *has* changed between .NET versions. If you want higher-fidelity testing, use SQLite in in-memory mode *and* ensure you use `OrderBy`

Comment: @Rafalon Good spot, yes I changed it to debug whether it was returning the last one in the collection. You're right that the result.ElementAt(2) throws an exception. Even when it given the correct Mode, it only returns 1.